# getrandbits doesn't return the exact length

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to get a key with a certain length. When I test, I don't get the length that I want.

For example, for `k=1000`, I get a key of length of either `301` or `302`, with the both statements `getrandbits` or with `randrange`.

my code:

```
def generate_prime(k,d):
    temp=1
    while not millerRabin(temp,d):
        temp=getrandbits(k)
        #temp= randrange(1 << k-1, 1 << k)
    return temp
```

Example run: `k=1000` - Result `301`:

```
k=1000
print(len(str(generate_prime(k,40))))
```

Comment: hint: what if the first bit generated is a zero?

Comment: randrange(1 << k-1, 1 << k) this line i think makes the the most left bit at 1 but it's always the same result as getranbits

Comment: When I print `len(str(getrandbits(500)))` I get 150 or 151, which I would expect when a 500-bit number is converted to decimal. How are you getting 301?

Comment: It’s just a mistake when i put 1000 i get 301

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want 1000 *digits*, not 1000 *bits*. Just use `randrange` on the range of 1000-digit numbers.

```
low = 10**(k-1)
high = 10 * low
temp = randrange(low, high)
```